# Solr - Score is always coming 0

Tags: solr, relevance

I am new to Solr. I have done indexing of web pages and getting the search result. But all results have

"score" = 0
  "boost" = 0

As a result  my search results are not sorted properly. At present my results are lexicographically sorted based on urls of web pages. I am specifying fl=*,score in my query.

I have specified following parameters for indexing "content" field of web pages

field name="content" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" omitNorms = "false

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somewhere the float value converted to integer?

```
<result name="response" numFound="16" start="0" maxScore="0.008373434">
<doc>
   <float name="score">0.008373434</float>
   <str name="id">301</str>
   <str name="ename">exampleName</str>
</doc>
    ...
```